# Where is font 'nametofont' in python33?

Tags: fonts, tkinter, python-3.3

This code generates an error:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.font import Font, nametofont

default_font = Font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\__P\nametofont.pyw", line 4, in <module>
    default_font = Font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
AttributeError: type object 'Font' has no attribute 'nametofont'
>>>
```

How do I get access to 'nametofont'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what I needed. Here is the modified and working code, with an added print statement:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.font import Font, nametofont

root = Tk()
default_font = nametofont("TkDefaultFont")
print(default_font)
```

The `Font.nametofont(...)` needed to be just `nametofont(...)`, and then it needed the `TK()` to get a window context to look in.

Answer (score 1):

Module `tkinter.font`

```
# Tkinter font wrapper
#
# written by Fredrik Lundh, February 1998
#

__version__ = "0.9"

import itertools
import tkinter


# weight/slant
NORMAL = "normal"
ROMAN = "roman"
BOLD   = "bold"
ITALIC = "italic"


def nametofont(name):
    """Given the name of a tk named font, returns a Font representation.
    """
    return Font(name=name, exists=True)
```

It could be that you need to write `font.nametofont` instead of `Font.nametofont`. The class may not have this attribute.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I needed to eliminate the 'Font.' in front of nametofont. This call is in a class within a much larger app.

Comment: Do this: `Font.nametofont = nametofont` which is monkeypatching th eattribute into the class so that you remove this error.